# golan creating a output of sum of squares for inputted integers

Tags: go

I've created a calculator that calcualtes the sum of squares of given integers excluding any negatives in go lang.

The problem I am facing is, I would like to make output show when I am done inputting all the inputs.such as,

sample input:

```
2
4
3 -1 1 14
5
9 6 -53 32 16
```

sample output :

```
206
1397
```

Instead, when my output for the first case ends, the first case is automatically calculated in the form where output is given before I can finish all inputs I would like.
How could I make no output shown until all the inputs are received?

```
// Calculate the sum of squares of given integers, excluding any negatives In Go lang
// Code written by Pintu Sharma

// Enter Total number of test cases := N
// N Times :
// Enter Total number of values.    := num
// Enter [num] times int values
// sample input:
// 2
// 4
// 3 -1 1 14
// 5
// 9 6 -53 32 16

// sample output :
// 206
// 1397


// sum of square, only positive numbers without using any loop
// Thats why i use recurssion in Go

// my Code in Go lang

package main

import "fmt"

// Taking Number of Test Cases and values

func test_cases(n int) {
    if n <= 0 {
        return
    }
    var num int
    // total number of values
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &num)
    fmt.Println(sum_of_square(num))
    test_cases(n-1)
}

// Calculating sum of square for each test case

func sum_of_square(value_count int) int {
    if value_count == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    var value int
    // take input value for generating sum of square
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &value)
    // if only value is positive
    if value > 0 {
        return value*value + sum_of_square(value_count - 1)
    }
    return sum_of_square(value_count - 1)
}

// Main function

func main() {
    var N int
    // number of total Test Cases
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &N)
    // Take input for each Test Case
    test_cases(N)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value after reading it in the recursive call.

```
func sum_of_square(value_count int) int {
    if value_count == 0 {
        fmt.Println()
        return 0
    }
    var value int
    // take input value for generating sum of square
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &value)
    // if only value is positive
    fmt.Print(strconv.Itoa(value) + " ")
    if value > 0 {
        return value*value + sum_of_square(value_count - 1)
    }
    return sum_of_square(value_count - 1)
}
```

The statement `fmt.Scanf("%d", &value)` prints the value after it is read.
After all the values are read  `fmt.Println()` will add a new line.